# I want to add a foreign key to an existing table - MariaDB 10.2

Tags: mariadb, foreign-key

```
  create table registered_user(
    userid serial primary key not null,
    name varchar(255) not null,
    surname varchar(255) not null,
    email varchar(100) not null,
    username varchar(255) not null unique,
    password varchar(255) not null,
    bibliography varchar(1024),
    avatar varchar(255),
    company varchar(100),
    lastactivity varchar(1024),
    banned boolean,
    admin boolean
  )engine=innodb;
```

```
  create table question(
    questionid serial primary key not null,
    createdby integer not null,
    title varchar(255) not null,
    content text not null,
  )engine=innodb;
```

I want to add foreign key createdby and have it reference registered_user(user_id) but no matter how I try to alter the table under MariaDB it keeps telling me You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You use `SERIAL` datatype for `userid` column. This datatype is an alias of `BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT`. So the column `createdby` which you want to be referred to `userid` must have the same datatype `BIGINT UNSIGNED` and not `integer`:

```sql
ALTER TABLE question
  MODIFY COLUMN createdby BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (createdby) REFERENCES registered_user (userid);
SHOW CREATE TABLE question;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/BN7x13YD